# How to know where is called function's position in in php?

Tags: php, class

I have 3 class name "**Controller**","**Loader**","**Error**" and "**Ex_controller**".

"**Controller.php**"

```
class Controller
{
     function __Construct()
     {
           $this->load = Loader::getinstant();
           $this->error = $this->load->class('Error');
     }
}
```

"**Loader.php**"

```
class Loader
{
     function class($class)
     {
           require_once($class);
           return new $class;
     }
}
```

"**Error.php**"

```
class Error
{
     function query($query)
     {
           $res = mysql_query($query)
           if($res)
           {
                  return $res;
           }else{
                  die('Could not execute query: '.mysql_error().'at line '. __LINE__ . 
                       ' in file ' . __FILE__);//does it work?If it doesn't, how to
                                                 make it work?
           }
     }
}
```

"**Ex_controller.php**"

```
class Ex_controller extends Controller
{
     function __Construct()
     {
           parent::__construct();
           $result = $this->error->query('some sql query');//(*)
     }
}
```

How can I show where the error occur in **Ex_controller** with (*)?

Comment: Why does `Error` class have a `query()` method? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should stop using `mysql_xxx` functions as they're in the process of deprecating the old API.

That aside, in this case, it's probably worthwhile to start using exceptions instead of a plain old `die()`.

```
if($res) {
    return $res;
}else{
    throw new Exception("Could not execute query '$query': " . mysql_error());
}
```

Then inside the controller:

```
try {
    $result = $this->error->query('some sql query');//(*)
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die(print_r($e, true)); // do something more useful with the exception though.
}
```

When you catch the exception higher up and you would `print_r()` it, you will see the complete stack trace with files, line numbers and everything.

Plus, you get the chance to handle the error as well.

Plus plus, if you would use `PDO` with exception error handling enabled, you don't even have to throw exceptions yourself anymore.

Comment: Thanks bro!But when I use it, localhost return me HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error).It's log seem to be nothing wrong happen here! How can I fix it?

Comment: @quanganh_developer You have to `try { } catch` the exception of course :)

Comment: You save my life :D! Can I use mysqli_xxx instead of mysql_xxx?

Comment: @quanganh_developer Yep, `mysqli` is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

At your class Ex_controller extends Controller
add

```
parent::__construct();
```

on the first line of __Construct() function

How ever the error class should returns only errors not to make queries....